Expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce` in Telegram-Bot with teloxide
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let bot = Bot::new(TG_TOKEN);
    let mut users = load_users()?;  

    teloxide::repl(bot, |bot: Bot, msg: Message| async move{
        let text = msg.text().unwrap();

        match text {
            "/start" => {
                bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, TEXT1).await.unwrap();
                let user = User::new(msg.chat.username().unwrap().to_string(), msg.chat.id);
                users.insert(user); 
            }
            "/status" => { bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, TEXT2).await.unwrap(); }
            &_ => {}
        };
        
        
        Ok(())
    }).await;
    Ok(())
}

I need to save and update users collection, it's HashSet when user is calling /start
but i get this error
Expected a closure that implements the Fn trait, but this closure only implements FnOnce
Here is full error from cargo check

error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`                                                                       
  --> src\main.rs:39:22
   |
39 |       teloxide::repl(bot, |bot: Bot, msg: Message| async move{
   |       --------------      -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |       |                   |
   |  _____|___________________this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`
   | |     |
   | |     required by a bound introduced by this call
40 | |         let text = msg.text().unwrap();
41 | |
42 | |         match text {
...  |
46 | |                 users.insert(user);
   | |                 ----- closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `users` out of its environment
...  |
53 | |         Ok(())
54 | |     }).await;
   | |_____- the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
   |
   = note: required for `{closure@src\main.rs:39:22: 39:46}` to implement `Injectable<DependencyMap, Result<(), RequestError>, (Bot, teloxide::prelude::Message)>`
note: required by a bound in `teloxide::repl`
  --> C:\Users\gogle\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\teloxide-0.12.2\src\repls\repl.rs:56:8
   |
52 | pub async fn repl<R, H, Args>(bot: R, handler: H)
   |              ---- required by a bound in this function
...
56 |     H: Injectable<DependencyMap, ResponseResult<()>, Args> + Send + Sync + 'static,
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `repl`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0525`.
error: could not compile `jaser_bot` (bin "jaser_bot") due to 1 previous error

idc how to fix this
I tried to create a wrapper around collection of users with 'a lifetime, but this doesn't help

You need to wrap the users in an Arc<Mutex<_>> and then clone before entering the async block:
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let bot = Bot::new(TG_TOKEN);
    let mut users = Arc::new(Mutex::new(load_users()?));  

    teloxide::repl(bot, move |bot: Bot, msg: Message|{
        let users_cloned = users.clone();
        async move{
            let text = msg.text().unwrap();

            match text {
                "/start" => {
                    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, TEXT1).await.unwrap();
                    let user = User::new(msg.chat.username().unwrap().to_string(), msg.chat.id);
                    users_cloned.lock().unwrap().insert(user); 
                }
                "/status" => { bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, TEXT2).await.unwrap(); }
                &_ => {}
            };


            Ok(())
        }}).await;
    Ok(())
}

This is because the closure needs to be Send, Sync and 'static. Therefore shared state, eg. Arc<Mutex<_>>, is necessary.
